# Invalid Error when Retrieving JSON API with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am passing a variable into a URL, which then calls an API filtered by the variable passed. However, I can't seem to get the JSON to load, and returns an Invalid Error in Console of Firebug in JS. Thoughts?

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var apiurl = "http://api.example.com" + $(this).text() + "&limit=500" + "?callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        url: apiurl,
        success: function(json) {alert(json.data.results);},
        error: function() { alert("error"); },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    });
});
```

This is the error:
invalid label
error source line:
[Break On This Error]
{"code":200,"status":"Ok","data":{"offset":0,"limit":500,"total":17,"target":"ch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove: `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"` from your request. Also you could use the [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method which is a shorthand for what you have written. And don't forget to return false from your click handler otherwise your call might never have time to execute before the browser redirects away following the `href` of the anchor that's being clicked. Another thin go to notice is that you should use `'&callback=?'` instead of `'?callback=?'` in the url because apparently you already have the `limit` query string parameter so you are just adding another one. I suppose in this case that `$(this).text()` contains somewhere the `?` which indicates the start of the query string:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var apiurl = 'http://api.example.com' + $(this).text() + '&limit=500' + '&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(apiurl, function(json) {
        alert(json.data.results);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Also I hope you realize that `callback=?` means [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) that the API that you are trying to invoke must support. Otherwise your call will always be failing because you are violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction.

Comment: I see, thanks for the insight. In this case, if I remove the callback=? string in the URL, the alert doesnt fire (nothing happens). I am working locally and requesting the API from another server. I was thinking JSONP would be the way to resolve this, but I might be missing something as I am fairly new to issues with JSON

Comment: also, how does one check for JSONP support?

Comment: Yes, if you are attempting to do a cross domain AJAX call you could use JSONP if the remote service supports it. If it doesn't you cannot invoke it from your script. In order to check whether the remote service supports JSONP there are 2 ways: 1. you go and read the documentation of the API you are trying to consume. 2. you attempt to put a sample request in the browser: `http://api.example.com?limit=500&callback=abc` and observe whether the returned JSON will be wrapped in an `abc` function. If it isn't there are 2 possibilities: 1. The remote server doesn't support JSONP or ...

Comment: 2. the parameter that allows you to specify the JSONP callback is not called `callback`. It this case you could try to guess it or contact the author of the API directly. It will be easier.

Comment: Also notice that I did a small correction in my answer. I replaced `'?callback=?'` at the end of the url with `'&callback=?'` because you already have the limit query string parameter, so callback is an additional parameter.

Comment: Thanks again, it seems like based on the conditions you provided, it might not support JSONP, in this case, developing locally to retrieve this api cross-domain wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If `"api.example.com"` is not on the same domain, you will need to use `dataType: 'jsonp'`.  [See jsonp docs](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) as well as [jQuery.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).